# The needed reason for create SO for our own languages

Tags: discussion

Like for example. I have seen SO had many different site for other languages: Russian and Japanese. What is requirement that need to observe before started making another SO for other language ? like SO for Chinese, etc.

Do we have to propose  this to Area 51 ? or we have to create our own server and make an agreement between SO and our own server ?

Comment: If you don't think there's enough detail in the answers already provided, perhaps your question isn't clear enough? What would a good answer tell you? The link to Area 51 that explains why they aren't creating new language-specific instances of SO is pretty clear and your other option is non-viable. What are you asking?

Comment: @Catija It's probably because there isn't a reason on MSE as to why such sites aren't created. But as of a few months ago, when I edited it into an answer here as the anonymous editor, there actually is, so this question is a dupe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Did we have to propose this to Area 51 ?

Normally, I would say yes, as this is the route most language sites took (though the Russian one was created outside of the network, was bought out and migrated to the network).

However - we are currently not accepting such proposals:

[Internationalization 'State of the Stack' - Stack Overflow edition](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20987/internationalization-state-of-the-stack-stack-overflow-edition)

> or we have to create our own server and make an agreement between SO and our own server ?

Not sure how that's supposed to work. It isn't how the current language sites were created. There's no guarantee that will work at all.

---

Either of these options is unlikely to end up with a new Stack Overflow in [language] site in the network - and frankly, I don't see any other option that would, at this point in time.